# How can an adapter from a third-party library be injected into RecyclerView's adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crashlytics

The Firebase crash below has been reported.

[image]

What I'm interested in is not the cause of the crash, but the class name of the adapter. The class name of the adapter I used is NearbySearchResultAdapter, but the class name in the log above is different. (Proguard is applied, but the package name is different)

[image]

My fragment is using Hilt as shown in the image below. Does this allow adapters from 3rd party libraries to be injected into my adapter?

[image]

I don't know what to do or how to do it.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  There's no adapted readable in the crash you posted.  And the crash has nothing to do with the adapter.  Also adapters aren't injected into recyclerviews at all.  You manually set them via setAdapter.  So no, hilt isn't injecting the wrong thing, unless you have a mistake at a much higher level.

Comment: @GabeSechan The point of my question is why the class name of the adapter passed in setAdapter and the class name in the crash log are different. I also don't think this has anything to do with the cause of the crash. I'm just curious why the class from the 3rd party lib package appears in the adapter name of crash log.